# Binding a Combobox within a DataTemplate correctly in Wpf

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I am trying to bind the ComboBox below to the list of Characters in the ObservableCollection, but it wont show anything. Any ideas why?

XAML:

```
    <TabControl ItemsSource ="{Binding TextEditors}"
     <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
       <ListBox> ItemsSource="{Binding TextLines}"
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>


               <ComboBox 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.InvCharacter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" 
                   DisplayMemberPath="name" 
                   SelectedValuePath="cid" 
                   SelectedValue="{Binding cid}">
               </ComboBox>


          </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       </ListBox>
      </DataTemplate>
     </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

this is the class i am referring to:

```
     class TextEditorVM: IViewModel {
         public ObservableCollection<TextLineVM> TextLines { get { return textLines; } set { textLines = value;} }
         public ObservableCollection<T_Character> InvCharacters { get { return invCharacters; } set { invCharacters = value; } }


         public TextEditorVM(T_Dialogue dialogue)
         {

             DialogueManager.Instance.Register(this);
             this.TextLines = new ObservableCollection<TextLineVM>();
             this.InvCharacters = new ObservableCollection<T_Character>();
         }
    }
```

and the MainVM:

```
     class MainVM : IViewModel
     {
           public ObservableCollection<TextEditorVM> TextEditors { get { return textEditors; } set { textEditors = value; OnPropertyChanged("TextEditors"); } 
     }
```

my T_Character Class looks like this now :

```
    public class T_Character
    {

       public String cid { get; set; }
       public String name { get; set; }

       public T_Character(String cid, String name)
       {
          this.cid = cid;
          this.name = name;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the `TabControl` is of type `MainVM`. The `RelativeSource` of the `ComboBox` binding should not be the `TabControl` but rather the `ListBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `InvCharacters` property is on your `TextEditorVM` object which is in your `ObservableCollection`, however your binding is referencing `TabControl.DataContext`, which is  `MainVM`, and does not contain that property.

Switch your RelativeSource binding to reference `TabItem` (it gets created automatically when you bind `TabControl.ItemsSource`) or `ListBox` to reference your `TextEditorVM` object

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.InvCharacters, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}">
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thank you so far, i have made some changes in the XAML due to your example. Also i have posted the T_Character Class above. I think i need to change the SelectedValue part but i dont know how. Do you have any idea?